# "Resources" tag ambuguity

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have a [resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) tag used by 5 questions so far - 4 of them deal with world resources, but there's [this one](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1396/are-there-any-free-science-fiction-world-settings) asking for worldbuilding resources.

I think that the tag itself should be used for worlds, rather than "tool" or "asset" resources - however, due to the nature of most tags we have, there isn't really a way to tag this unless what you're asking for clearly falls into the scope of [map-making](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/map-making) or [worldbuilding-process](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worldbuilding-process), the former being too specific and the latter too broad, if you're just asking for possible websites with map images or a world archive (just an example).

I tried to think of another tag, but the problem is, it has to be intuitive enough that someone, upon trying to tag their question with [resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) and seeing that it's not for what they intend, wouldn't have a problem guessing the correct tag - and I can't think of anything.

Does anyone have a good idea for such a tag-name? Is this a non-issue, since it may not really come up again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe we should add the tag: natural resources

Comment: replace `resources` with `worldbuilding-resources` and `natural-resources` so newcomers will instantly know what each can be used for?

Comment: That's pretty good - I think what I'll do is, I'll change [tag:resources] to [tag:natural-resources] and create a [tag:worldbuilding-resources] tag (since we already have [tag:worldbuilding-process] - I completely forgot that when you type in the tag bar, it does a search and presents options. This should both clarify the intent and allow using "resources" both ways. Nice!

Comment: This would mean that each time someone starts to type `resources` as a tag, both these would show up as suggestions.

Comment: @githubphagocyte lol we posted at like the exact same moment, yeah that's what I'll do

Comment: @ivy_lynx sounds perfect, if I do say so myself... :)

Comment: Personally, I would prefer software-resources over worldbuilding-resources because the later is still pretty vague.

Comment: I agree with @Vincent, software-resources is the better idea.

Comment: Perhaps educational-resources?