# Fixing the resources tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tag-synonyms

I looked this up and it turns out that, [back in 2014](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346/resources-tag-ambuguity), there was a tag for [resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) and people wanted resources of a world to be separate from resources for building a world.  So they turned it into two tags: [natural-resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-resources) and [worldbuilding-resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worldbuilding-resources)

All well and good.

But it seems someone re-created [resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources).  We don't need this tag.  It's a duplicate of [natural-resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-resources).  I tried to suggest it be a synonym but I don't have enough points in the tag.

The wiki for [natural-resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-resources) (total: 116 questions):

> For questions that deal with the natural resources found in the
>   environment.
>
> Natural resources are naturally found in the environment. It encompass
>   resources that were not transformed by humans or other intelligent
>   species. Examples include energy resources like oil, coal, uranium;
>   metals: gold, silver, copper, iron; building material: sand, stone,
>   marble. Air and water can also be considered as natural resources.

The wiki for [resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) (total: 3 questions):

> For questions about the natural resources of a world. Not for
>   questions about resources useful to the author in making a world (use
>   worldbuilding-resources instead).

Could a moderator please turn [resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) into a synonym for [natural-resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-resources)?  If we simply fix the tags and get rid of [resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) altogether, we'll end up with someone creating it again.

Answer (score 9):

Done.  Normally I'm not keen on substring aliases (typing "resources" causes the existing tags to pop up), but since this tag has already been recreated once after we fixed it, I went ahead and defined the synonym after merging.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks.